# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'projects.company_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can any one help me to solve this error.

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'projects.company_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`company_id` = 2  ORDER BY position ASC
  Rendered project/index.html.erb within layouts/application (22.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 89.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'projects.company_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`company_id` = 2  ORDER BY position ASC):
    12:      <th> Actions </th>
    13:    </tr>
    14: 
    15:    <%= @projects.each do |project| %>
    16:    <tr>
    17:     <td><%= project.company.name if project.company %></td>
    18:     <td><%= project.name %></td>
  app/views/project/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_project_index_html_erb__831754569244709537_70147764435580'


  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (58.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (44.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/ajaysithagari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (98.5ms)
```

Comment: 1) Format your question. 2) Post the code that generated the error. 3) Post ant code that is related to this (like models), etc.

Comment: show us your models. is there are 2 models called project and company? and relation is project has one company and company has many projects?

Comment: Please add more details like model association, may be you don't have column "company_id" in your project table

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Gupta, yeah Iforgot to link the tables thanks for replay

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you just need to add the company_id field to the Project model.

```
rails generate migration AddCompanyIdToProject company_id:integer:index
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Project` table have column `company_id`

```
rails generate migration AddCompanyIdToProject company:references
rake db:migrate
```